# Is there any placeholder value that can be used in a MongoDB aggregation lookup, to find the right field in an object of objects?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, lookup

I have two collections, where the first one has foreign keys of the second collection. Now I want to aggregate the matching data of the second collection. The problem is, that I don't know to properly define the path of the `localField`, because it's in an object of objects.
It will be changed to an array of objects at some point, but for now I have to deal with it. The collection structures look like this:

collectionOne

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('...'),
  groups: {
    '1': {
      things: [{
        id: xyz,
        foreignId: ObjectID('001') // id of collectionTwo
      }]
    },
    '2': {
      things: [{
        id: zyx,
        foreignId: ObjectId('001') // id of collectionTwo
      }]
    },
  }
}
```

collectionTwo

```
{
  _id: ObjectID('001').
  ...
}
```

I've read through the docs and searched here and elsewhere, but I didn't find any matching case. 
For arrays I know I don't have to specify the actual place in the array. So if `groups` would also be an array of objects I could just use the dot operator like this:

```
collectionOne.aggregate([
      {$match: {_id, ObjectID('...')},
      {$lookup: {
        from: 'collectionTwo',
        localField: 'groups.things.foreignId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'aggregatedThings'
      }},
    ])
```

So I want to set `localField` to a path, that matches every object in `groups`. Something like this, where `$` is a placeholder for every key:

```
collectionOne.aggregate([
      {$match: {_id, ObjectID('...')},
      {$lookup: {
        from: 'collectionTwo',
        localField: 'groups.$.things.foreignId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'aggregatedThings'
      }},
    ])
```

I hope my problem is clear.
Appreciate any help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this.

```
collectionOne.aggregate([
      {$match: {_id, ObjectID('...')},
      { '$addFields': {
        'groupsArray': { $objectToArray: '$groups' }
      }},
      {$lookup: {
        from: 'collectionTwo',
        localField: 'groupsArray.v.things.foreignId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'aggregatedThings'
      }},
    ])
```

Converting the object to an Array using `$objectToArray` does the trick for me.